# How to use variable of condition inside the block

Tags: ruby

How can I use the var `string` of the condition in the return value?

```
lines = ["dyfögifuödxfghif", "xdghödfx", "abcdefg"]
strings = ["abc", "zzzzzzzzz"]
lines.each do |line|
    if strings.any? { |string| line.include?(string) }
        return string
    end
end
return nil
```

Datatypes:

```
lines:Array, line:String, strings:Array, string:String
```

Desired result:

```
=> "abc"
```

I am iterating through a lot of lines and want to check each of them if they include a string inside the array named `strings` -> until I either find a match, or finished iterating.

*This snippet **does** work, but it does the same thing **twice**:*

```
lines.each do |line|
    if strings.any? { |string| line.include?(string) }
        return strings.detect { |string| line.include?(string) }
    end
end
return nil
```

Comment: That comments below suggest that readers do not understand what you want. That could be cleared up by providing an example with `strings` and `line` that includes your desired result. Also explain what you want returned when there is no match.  When you give an example (generally a good thing) assign a variable to each input object (e.g, `line = "..."; strings = ["...", "...",...]`) so that readers can refer to those variables without having to define them.

Comment: The way you've changed the question is equivalent to both answers so far that use `detect` (aka `find`). That is, `detect` returns the first `string` for which `line.include?(string)` is `true`, or `nil` if no `string` satisfies that requirement.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the point is that `detect` is returning the first match **or** `nil`. That is not what I want. I want to iterate until I either find a match, or iterated through the entire `lines` array.

Comment: I think most readers assumed `line` was a string, not an array, mainly because `line` is a good name for a string but a misleading name for an array. If you had said `line` was an array, named it something like `lines` or given your example initially (or best, given it a good name and provide an example) you wouldn't have had this misunderstanding.  You still haven't shown the desired result for the example.

Comment: Do you want every matching occurrence or only the first?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `line:String`, `lines:Array`

Comment: Please include that information by editing your question. Not all readers read all comments.

Comment: @theTinMan how could I get all?

Comment: Start by reading "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)", then when you've accomplished those steps ask a specific question about that code. This question isn't well asked as evidenced by the repeated changes and multiple comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`detect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
return strings.detect { |string| lines.any? { |line| line.include?(string) } }
```

Comment: problem is that this will return nil without a match. I want to return the first match, therefore the if statement.

Comment: Then I return nil

Comment: @jonhue if you want to return nil when there isn't a match, that's exactly what `detect` already does.

Comment: I am iterating through a lot of lines and want to check each of them if they include a string inside the array named `strings` -> until I either find a match, or finished iterating :)

Comment: It is a very simple task so it got to be fine

Answer (score 2):

You could use .find with some regex to bring back the first match

```
strings.find {|word| lines.find {|line| line =~ /#{word}/ } }
=> "abc"


# if you want all matches 
strings.select {|word| lines.find {|line| line =~ /#{word}/  } }
=> ["abc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first match:

```
strings.detect { |string| line.include?(string) }
```

If you want all matches (in an array):

```
strings.select { |string| line.include?(string) }
```

Comment: With that I could use something like this: `if strings.any? { |string| line.include?(string) }
                            string = strings.detect { |string| line.include?(string) }
                            return string
                        end` but that feels quite double doubled ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily if you compile the list of strings to match into a compact regular expression:

```
string_rx = Regexp.union(strings)
```

Then all you have to do is filter out the lines that match and pull off the first one:

```
lines.grep(string_rx).first
# => "abcdefg"
```

If you don't want to have to process the entire array and optimize this for performance:

```
lines.lazy.grep(string_rx).first
# => "abcdefg"
```

The `lazy` designator makes each entry flow through the chain to completion rather than each stage buffering up before passing to the next.